# Action and soapAction compatibility with Java and WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I’m working on WCF but I have a problem, the WSDL generated in Java that was provided, has some configuration that does not match with WCF configuration.
The point is that the WSDL requires to set the Action in the portType operations but to set the soapAction empty in binding Attribute as follows:

**This is what I need:**

```
<portType name="Service1">
        <operation name="operation1">
          <input wsam:Action="http://www. wwwmyUrl.com / Service1/ operation1Request" message="tns: operation1 "/>
          <output wsam:Action="http://www. wwwmyUrl.com / Service1/ operation1Response" message="tns: operation1 Response"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="Service1ImplPortBinding" type="tns: Service1 ">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <operation name=" operation1">
          <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
          <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </input>
          <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
```

I set the attribute  in the Interface operation

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="", ReplyAction= "")]
```

but it removes the Action from the porType and it does not match with the required.

**This is the Result:**

```
<portType name="Service1">
    <operation name="operation1">
      <input wsam:Action=" " message="tns: operation1 "/>
      <output wsam:Action=" " message="tns: operation1 Response"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="Service1ImplPortBinding" type="tns: Service1 ">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name=" operation1">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
```